# Making file manager app in Android Studio and can't write to storage

Tags: java, android, file-permissions, delete-file, android-external-storage

I'm following a now outdated [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mG9t7-NYUM0&t=3s) on making a file manager in Android Studio and I'm having a bit of trouble with writing to the storage device. The app runs and displays all the files and folders in the app but when I try to use the `delete file` button, nothing happens and the logcat just displays

`W  sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17@e07288e`

I believe it's because it doesn't receive the permissions it needs.
Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.FileManagerTut"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <activity
            android:name=".FileListActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My MainActivity where the read permissions are set:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MaterialButton storageBtn = findViewById(R.id.storage_btn);

        storageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                    if(checkPermission()){
                        //permission allowed
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FileListActivity.class);
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                        intent.putExtra("path",path);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        //permission not allowed
                        requestPermission();

                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private boolean checkPermission(){
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    private void requestPermission(){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Storage permission is requires,please allow from settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES},111);
    }
}
```

and myAdapter class where the the actions on the files and folders are created:

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    File[] filesAndFolders;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, File[] filesAndFolders){
        this.context = context;
        this.filesAndFolders = filesAndFolders;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        File selectedFile = filesAndFolders[position];
        holder.textView.setText(selectedFile.getName());

        if(selectedFile.isDirectory()){
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
        }else{
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_insert_drive_file_24);
        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(selectedFile.isDirectory()){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, FileListActivity.class);
                    String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    intent.putExtra("path", path);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }else {
                    //open the file
                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        String type = "image/*";
                        //add for audio, video, image files
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath()), type);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Cannot open the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(context, v);
                popupMenu.getMenu().add("DELETE");
                popupMenu.getMenu().add("MOVE");
                popupMenu.getMenu().add("RENAME");

                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        if(Objects.equals(item.getTitle(), "DELETE")) {
                            boolean deleted = selectedFile.delete();
                            if(deleted) {
                                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        }
                        if(Objects.equals(item.getTitle(), "MOVE")) {
                            //move
                        }
                        if(Objects.equals(item.getTitle(), "RENAME")) {
                            //rename
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popupMenu.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filesAndFolders.length;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name_text_view);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_view);
        }
    }
}
```

You can see here that once I long press on the file and press the delete button, the `boolean deleted` is still false.
[image]

I tried the answers from similar questions I found but nothing works so far and many of them were written before file permissions changed. Can anyone help?

Comment: To delete a file you need a WRITE permission in Android 12 devices and lower.

Comment: Further you can never make a usable file manager without implementing MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: Post all code as text. No images please.

Comment: `selectedFile.delete()` If that is on a directory it will only be successfull if the directory is empty.

Comment: I only added that as an image because it shows the debug information after I press the delete button. I can remove it if it's not necessary. I also haven't tried to delete a directory yet. selectedFile is an image file that I moved onto the emulator.

Comment: Try selectedFile.canWrite() before you try to delete.

Comment: Further it is strange that you did not react on all comments. Starting with the first one.

Comment: Display file.getName() in popupmenu.